# Failed to run command `/opt/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java': No such file or directory

Tags: java, centos6

I have java environment installed on my server

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

Java Setup variables Path:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_171
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_171/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_171/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/bin
```

When i run my application that use java i still get this error even its installed

```
nohup: failed to run command `/opt/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java': No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error message references **131**, while everything else above has **171**?

Comment: Right i installed the latest java version or should i use the exact same version shown on error msg?

Comment: you can just change the directory name which you have in your machine, that would work @user

Comment: I depends on how the error is occurring. What application do you try to start? Maybe this has a hard-coded JDK - if so you would need to fix it here or create something like a symlink. Tell us what you tried to run via nohup.

Comment: its php application that use java also it needs phantomjs

Comment: @OmerStimpack: php does not need java - what is calling the java and how?

Comment: so it worked for  you? @OmerStimpack

Answer (score 1):

First modify the .bashrc file like below, you don't need JRE_HOME

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_171
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This would be sufficient, and chown that jdk1.8.0_171 to user level

```
sudo chown user:group jdk1.8.0_171
```

For Example **sudo chown deadpool:deadpool jdk1.8.0_171**
And check **java -v** and **which java**

Observe the Error its looking for directory **jdk1.8.0_131** but in path your directory is **jdk1.8.0_171**

Comment: the .bashrc file looks like this `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin    export PATH` should i add the given code in the bottom without removing anything or replace it?

Comment: i prefer replacing PATH with this` export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH ` @OmerStimpack

Comment: removing the code `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin export PATH` will stop searching for applications in home directory ... Following should keep both in path, your home and the JDK (I just hope you know what path is): `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HOME/bin; export PATH` or `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HOME/bin`